# Hit back on browsercause JavaScript Variables mix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got webpage with JS code that get randomize Object from array and show it's value with Jquery .html()  code in some div.
That work great.

When I click on a another page on the website it also look great, but when I click back on the browser, the code what created max the JavaScript Variables and I get the wrong text in the wrong placement

Any Tip what should I look for?

```
function showMoodaa(size, divID, countshow) {
    if (typeof(countshow) === 'undefined')
        countshow = 1;
    var rndBanner = "";
    var htmlcode = "";
    if (modaoot[size] != undefined) {
        if (countshow > 1) {
            var countMoodaa = modaoot[size].length;
            if (countMoodaa > countshow) {
                countMoodaa = countshow;
            }
            rndBanner = Math.floor(Math.random() * modaoot[size].length);
            for (i = 0; i < countMoodaa; i++) {
                if ((rndBanner + i) >= modaoot[size].length) {
                    htmlcode = htmlcode + (modaoot[size][rndBanner + i - countMoodaa].html);
                    window.numBanner = window.numBanner + modaoot[size][rndBanner + i - countMoodaa].id + ",";
                } else {
                    htmlcode = htmlcode + (modaoot[size][rndBanner + i].html);
                    window.numBanner = window.numBanner + modaoot[size][rndBanner + i].id + ",";
                }
            }

        } else {
            rndBanner = Math.floor(Math.random() * modaoot[size].length);
            window.numBanner = window.numBanner + modaoot[size][rndBanner].id + ",";
            htmlcode = modaoot[size][rndBanner].html;

        }
    } else {
        htmlcode = "<!-- no size like this in array-->";
    }

    $("#" + divID).append(htmlcode);

}

showMoodaa(2, "pos1");
showMoodaa(2, "pos2");
showMoodaa(10, "pos1", 2);
```

Comment: we need to see an example of bad behaviour as well as a correct representation of the wanted behaviour. IF you generate stuff as random, how do you expect it to not be random later?

Comment: when is this function executed? might help to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){ /* Your function calls here */ });` this will this will make your code execute when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Dellirium every array has some type of Object  size, I get the wrong size when calling  modaoot[size]

Comment: @Mike it all in document.ready function

Comment: @boaz in your code moodaa is never defined within this function, so I am guessing its from its parental scope, what is it, though we dont know